# How can I configure the Aiptek T-6000U graphics tablet?

Tags: 11.04, xorg, input-devices, graphics-tablet

I followed [AiptekTablet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AiptekTablet) instructions on the Ubuntu Wiki to configure 11.04 for use with my graphics tablet.

I installed the `xserver-xorg-input-aiptek` package and created two files with the options detailed on the Wiki page above:

```
$ cat /lib/udev/rules.d/69-xserver-xorg-input-aiptek.rules
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="xorg_aiptek_end"
KERNEL!="event[0-9]*", GOTO="xorg_aiptek_end"
ATTRS{idVendor}=="08ca", ENV{x11_driver}="aiptek", SYMLINK+="input/aiptektablet"
LABEL="xorg_aiptek_end"

$ cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-aiptek.conf
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "pen"
        MatchProduct "Aiptek|AIPTEK|aiptek"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "aiptek"
        Option "USB" "on"
        Option "Type" "stylus"
        Option "Mode" "absolute"
        Option "zMin" "0"
        Option "zMax" "511"
EndSection
```

The `50-aiptek.conf` file was originally called `10-aiptek.conf` as in the Wiki, but an [Aiptek tablet installation help](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1746323) thread on the Ubuntu Forums, suggested changing 10 to 50.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I've asked a question on 
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=aiptektablet-users

Comment: Could you please provide a more specific link and an explanation for completeness and for the case that the link dies?